# Using functions to determine min or max

Tags: c, function, loops

I want to write a C program that takes a user input and compares the previous values for the minimum and maximum values. The trouble that i'm having is the comparison of values keeps resetting itself rather than using previously entered values to use as the min and max. The program will use a end of file loop to stop the program.....

Here is my attempt at the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//variables for the functions:
double MinMax(double a);

//main program 

int main (){
    double num;
    while (num!=EOF){
        printf("Enter a real number: ");
        scanf("%lf",&num);
        MinMax(num);
    }
    return 0; 
}

//function 
double MinMax (double a){
    double max=0,min=0; 
    if (a>max){
        max=a;
    }
    else if (a<min){
        min=a;
    }
    else {
    }
    printf("The max is %lf and the min is %lf\n",max,min);
}
```

Comment: Max and min are set to zero everytime you call the function and you can not store variables inside a function. You should create a class which has those variables inside it and a function like the MinMax you have but without resetting the min and max to zero each time you call it inside that class. Then the class can store the variable info and everytime you call minmax it will update the info. Or as is said in the answers to pass the variables by reference.

Comment: "I want to write a C program" -- then you should tag the question C and not C++.

Comment: "I want to write a C++ program" -- then why is this code entirely C?

Comment: In `while (num!=EOF)` firstly `num` is *undefined* on the first loop, and possibly the next. Secondly it is `scanf` which returns `EOF` not the `double` value you enter. But even then it is better to check `while(scanf("%lf", &num) != 1)` for the number of items successfully scanned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
//variables for the functions
void MinMax(double a, double* max, double* min);

//main program
int main() {
    double num = 0;
    double min = 0;
    double max = 0;

    printf("Enter a real number: ");
    scanf("%lf",&num);

    //To exit the loop and avoid undefined behaviour
    while (num != -999) {    
        MinMax(num, &max, &min);
        printf("Enter a real number: ");
        scanf("%lf",&num);
    }

    return 0;
}

void MinMax (double a, double* max, double* min) {
    if (a > *max)
            *max = a;

    if (a < *min)
            *min = a;

    printf("The max is %lf and the min is %lf\n", *max, *min);
}
```

You may also choose to use:

```
static double max = 0, min = 0;
```

This would go on top of the MinMax function, but the best way to go about your problem is to use pointers to pass by reference. As demonstrated above:

```
void MinMax(double a, double* min, double* max)
```

**Note**: C uses * in prototype not &.

Happy coding.

Comment: You have repeated the `while (num!=EOF)` gaffe which is also *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @WeatherVane could you suggest a better way perhaps, thanks.

Comment: As in my above comment: `while(scanf("%lf", &num) != 1)` or possibly `== 1` depending on the flow logic.

Comment: @twahanz using this program will not change the minimum value which is the same problem im having

Comment: @EdwinAndrew I have ran the code and it changes the min value.

Comment: @Twahanz your edit is still *undefined behaviour* since `num` is uninitialised. And you must **always** check the function return value of any of the `scanf` family. If you don't check it as part of the program logic, the loop will stall, since any bad input (say in this case `"a"`) will keep being scanned, *ad infinitum* unless you take steps to clear it out of the input buffer. One way you can do that is to read input with `fgets` and scan the string with `sscanf`.

Comment: @Weather Oh, I forgot about the uninitialized part. I will greatly appreciate if you edit the rest for me thanks.

Comment: I have given you some hints: but it is your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your code in two ways:

- Make `min` and `max` variables `static`, or
- Pass `min` and `max` through references.

First approach requires the following change:

```
static double max=0, min=0;
```

The second approach is more complex, but it is also better: `min` and `max` need to move to `main`, and the signature of `MinMax` needs to take them by reference:

```
double MinMax(double a, double& min, double& max);
```

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge but what does it mean to make min and max static? And for the second method how would it work because i know functions can only be used for one result?

Comment: @EdwinAndrew Static variables retain their values between invocations. Passing by reference lets a function change things without returning them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not saving, because you declare `min` and `max` within the scope of your function `MinMax`. So when the function returns, those variables are removed from the stack. If you want to use a function, I'd recommend passing in min and max by reference like this:

```
double MinMax(double a, double &min, double &max) {...}
```

So your updated values are saved between function calls.